# jquery date input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know if there is a date input plugin for jquery that work like this [plugin](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/) epecifically the datetimeinput. 
This input check that the values are correct and only let the user to input the numbers not the `/` characters for the date.

I know that there are some mask inputs plugins out there but I would like one that validates and only lets the user to input correct date.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Calendars Datepicker. They providing validation plugin also

You will get required info from [HERE](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this awesome [jquery plugin](http://pastebin.com/zxcKtXyN) fits your needs.

[Working demo code](http://pastebin.com/zxcKtXyN). However there are much more plugins just try a short search on [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20date%20plugin%20validation).

Comment: Thanks for your response Mythli will look at that demo.

Answer (score 0):

mongaru, why don't you use the plugin that you linked? It's free for personal use.

Comment: Yeah I like it for personal use but I want to use it on commercial applications.